# How to Make a .bat file with arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

For my work I have to run a string in "`run`".

I want to make this in a `bat` file but the arguments are not used but without them the program will not run.

This is the string:

```
"C:\Program files (x86)\MicroTouch\MT7\TwUI.exe" TwUICP.dll CPMain
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put the same line of code into your bat file:

```
"C:\Program files (x86)\MicroTouch\MT7\TwUI.exe" TwUICP.dll CPMain
```

There are some options you can use. For example if you want the program to run hidden in background you can add `start /b` before the line. `start /w` will make the cmd window stay open and wait for your program to finish. You can even definde which CPU cores the program should use. For more information open the console and type `start /?` or check out http://ss64.com/nt/start.html.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem, same software i think...

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MicroTouch\MT 7\TwUI.exe" twuicp.dll CPMain

Running that line through task manager -> new task will open a tool to configure touch-screen options, calibrate, etc...

Well same line doesnt work in a bat or cmd file. If i try to launch this tool through cmd.exe it doesnt work either.

The answer is always the same: 
    `USAGE: twui <DLL name> <UI symbol name>`

[This works, but same line in cmd.exe dont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5jfw.png)

Comment: Using start doesnt work for me. First try it answers there is no dll found in the path, second try it answers that theres no program associated to this.